# how to assign address to a pointer where address is store in CString object?

Tags: c++

```
CString str("0x1b1be0")
void* ptr = NULL;
```

Now i want to assign `ptr =  0x1b1be0`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you ever do anything with that Pointer, it's likely to be UB.

Comment: "Now i want to assign..." Why are you expecting this assignment to do anything useful?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: "Not useful" is far too weak to describe the idea of assigning a literal value (or user input) to a pointer. I'd call it a recipe for disaster - in the best case, the application will just crash when trying to do anything with the pointer. In the worst case, there's nasal demons...

Comment: i am taking memory address from user in hexadecimal and reading that memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CString str("0x1b1be0");
void* ptr = (void *)_tcstoul(str.GetBuffer(), 0, 0);
```

And this is in pure C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "0x1b1be0";
    void *p = (void *)strtoul(s, 0, 0);
    printf("%p", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Try it on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/ccVuvV7k).

**Note:** This version has no error checking.  Just to demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream s;
s << "0x1234";
void* a;
s >> std::hex >> a;
```

Comment: how can we achieve this in c i.e. instead of Cstring class we have char pointer storing address char* cptr = "0x1b1be0" and ptr = 0x1b1be0.

Comment: Probably with `sscanf`, but I don't know a safe solution (i.e. without the assumption that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: @Suri: You tagged your question as C++. If you explicitly want answers that work in C, you should use that tag instead. (I also love people who tag questions C and C++ at the same time and after several answers they comment that they actually were only interested in an answer for one language, but not the other...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    void * x;   
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << "0x1b1be0";
    ss >> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, unless you're writing something very low level such as a debugger, having to do such a thing is highly questionable...

Are you sure you know what a pointer means ?

Do you know that pointers are private to your process ? They most often have no meaning outside.

To answer your question, you obviously have to:

1. Convert your string to an `intptr_t` using for example `std::sscanf` with the `%x` format specifier.
2. Assign your pointer with `reinterpret_cast< void* >`.

Comment: `%x` will probably read `sizeof(int)`, so 4 bytes on 64-bit systems and `sizeof(void*)` will be 8 bytes, so I'd be really afraid here unless we're OK with some non-portable assumptions. But I'm also interested why would one need this besides debuggers...

Comment: `scanf("%x", &foo)` _will_ write `sizeof(int)` bytes (no more, no less); it typically reads many more (e.g. `"0xC0000005"` is ten bytes, but `0xC0000005` is only 4.). You're probably confused by `printf()` which works in the other direction (memory to standard out).